# Create a Post method to save an object with multiples id

Tags: java, spring

I have in my controller:

```
@RestController
public class OneTwoController {
    private OnTwoService _service;
//... more code
@PostMapping("/api/one-two")
@CrossOrigin
public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> save(@RequestBody OneTwo model) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body( _service.Save(model));
}
```

In my entity:

```
@Entity(name = "OneTwo")
@Where (clause = "deleted='false'")
public class OneTwo{
    @EmbeddedId
    private OneTwoKey_id;

    public OneTwo(OneTwoKey id) {
        this._id = id;
}

@JsonProperty("oneTwo")
    public void setId(OneTwoKey value) {
        this._id = value;
}
```

The OneTwoKey class:

```
public class OneTwoKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "OneID")
    private int _oneID;

    @Column(name = "TwoID")
    private int _twoID;

    public OneTwoKey(int oneID, int twoID) {
        this._oneID = oneID;
        this._twoID = twoID;
    }

}
```

The json that I send to the Rest API:

```
{
  "oneTwo": {
    "oneID": 83,
    "twoID": 69
  },
  "deleted": true
}
```

The issue is that both ids arrive null, so the service can't do the insert on the DB.

How can I deal with those cases when the ids are more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding setters in the `OneTwoKey` class to make it easier for the JSON deserializer:

```
@JsonProperty("oneID")
public void setOneID(int oneID) {
    this._oneID = oneID;
}

@JsonProperty("twoID")
public void setTwoID(int twoID) {
    this._twoID = twoID;
}
```

Another solution is to create a DTO, use it to receive the data in the controller and then convert it to your entity:

```
public class OneTwoDTO {
    private Map<String, Int> oneTwo;
    private boolean deleted;
    // setters & getters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply what you can do is instead of using

`public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> save(@RequestBody OneTwo model) {`

you can use

`public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> save(@RequestBody String model) {`

Now convert the String to json and get all the key value pairs, it would be easier if you have dynamic number of variables and you want to capture them all.

or you can use tools like [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) whick take a json schema and generate a pojo. In the json schema if you set 
`"additionalProperties": true`
you can capture all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make sure the problem is not because of case sensitivity?

Lower case the column names. Also could you use public access on those variables as well? These are my initial guesses as to why the payload is not being binded correctly.

```
public class OneTwoKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "oneID")
    public int _oneID;

    @Column(name = "twoID")
    public int _twoID;
```

Comment: Is not a issue due to case sesitive, but thanks anyway :)